# Playing with Android Http Request and Response

Tags: android, multithreading, httpresponse

I made a test project just testing http request and response behavior, There is a simple http class extending Asynctask to make request and get response. I am performing some string manipulation on http response, there is a problem my code which is using http response is executing before getting the response from class, which results null pointer exception. So to resolve this i made a thread and all code dependent on http response put in that thread. Now every thing is working fine.But i want to know is there any other technique to handle this? or my approach is good? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to know is there any other technique to handle this?

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for Android Http Request.

Comment: seems like AsyncTask is the only way

Comment: class already extends AsyncTask, but the class i am using in 10-12 different classes.

Comment: what you say i can't understand ?

Comment: i mean to say, i made a separate class for http request which extends AsyncTask, and whenever need to make request i just call that class. Pass url to constructor and call a user defined method getResponse(). Some time when i call getResponse method, i throw null pointer exception because http response not getting yet but calling class wants to use it.So i made thread to put some delay.

Comment: put thread fro delay is not solution see here http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-seperate-asynctask-class.html

Comment: @SamirMangroliya- thanks bro, i have solved this issue.now every thing is working as my wish.now i do not need to put thread for delay.